# Convert XmlSerializer code from java to C#

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, xmlserializer

I have a Java Android application that seralizes a document correctly, but I am required to build an equivalent using ASP.NET/C#.

XMLSerializer in Java and XmlSerializer in C# appear to be completely different animals. The Java version seems to have loads of methods not found in the C# version.

Here is an example of the code I have:

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    serializer.setOutput(writer); *
    serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true); *
    serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true); *
    serializer.startTag(null, "root"); *
    serializer.flush(); *
    writer.write(value);
    serializer.endTag(null, String.valueOf(type).toLowerCase()); *
    serializer.startTag(null, "image");
    serializer.text(Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT)); *
    serializer.endTag(null, "image");
    serializer.endDocument(); *
```

None of the methods listed here (marked with asterix) are available in C#. How can I possibly emulate it?
I have searched the net and can't find any decent documentation on the subject. Does anyone know what the C# equivalents would be for the methods shown above?

Comment: .startTag => WriteStartElement,
.endTag => WriteEndElement, etc. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlTextWriter_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.Flush` <-> `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer.flush`
- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(Stream)` <-> `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer.setOutput(Writer)`
- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteStartDocument` <-> `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer.startDocument`
- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteEndDocument` <-> `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer.endDocument`
- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteStartElement` <-> `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer.startTag`
- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteEndElement` <-> `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer.endTag`
- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteString` <-> `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer.text`
- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteBase64` <-> your image
- `System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction` <-> `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer.setFeature`

References on msdn:

1. [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), forward-only xml stream generator
2. [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. [XmlWriter encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
4. [Namespace Handling in the XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cfche0ka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)